# What are the high level requirements common to all business apps?

Tags: usability, requirements

I know that every application will have its unique requirements, and I am looking for something REAL high level such as the following where I could assign all other specific requirements under a topic.  I think my list is pretty good, but expect I missed some or maybe should combine some.

1. Enjoyable to use (UX, low learning curve, etc) to ensure adoption.
2. Provides real value to the intended audience (key word is "intended") so that adoption continues.
3. Good ROI (obviously needs to financially pencils out).
4. Longevity (maintainable, content remains relevant, scalable, etc).
5. Managed risk (exit plan, secure based on exposure, backup and recovery, etc).

Comment: Actually, I think ROI is the only one that matters to businesses, because all the other requirements either contribute or reduce the ROI if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

[IDEO's lenses of innovation](https://www.ideou.com/blogs/inspiration/what-is-design-thinking) that talks about the three elements which must come together to create a well-designed service or product is probably as high level as you can get. It is also where the famous Venn diagram comes from.

[image]

- Desirability: What makes sense to people and for people?
- Feasibility: What is technically possible within the foreseeable
  future
- Viability: What is likely to become part of a sustainable business
  model?

And under each of those business, design and technical requirements, you will then list out all the functional and non-functional requirements (and constraints) based on your particular company goals and customer base.